# 1/2 HP sewer pump, outlet reduction 1 1/2" - 1 1/4"

Tags: sump-pump

I have a 1/2 HP sewer pump to drop into septic tank and pump it out. The old pump has a 1 1/4" outlet, and the new pump has a 1 1/2" outlet.  Because I want to use the old  1 1/4" hose, I want to put a reducer 1 1/2" - 1 1/4" on the pump.  Will this cause the hose to blow off pump? Would a reduction 8 feet up the pipe be better?

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the hose diameter will increase the potential back pressure on the pump but if properly connected the reduction will be fine. Since you already have the 1-1/4" get a reducer and install it right at the pump.